# To which version should I update the Google Play Services SDK used in my app?

Tags: android, google-play-services

When developing an Android app, we do not want the minimum SDK version to be the latest released Android version (API 25 – Android 7.1 at the time of writing). We will look at the [Android version Dashboard page](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html) to see the version distribution and probably set the minimum SDK version to API 16~21, unless our app needs a specific functionality that is only available on the newer Android versions.

However, when using Google Play Services libraries, we never know which version of the SDK we should add to our app. At the time of writing (July 2017), recently they released these versions:

- June 2017 - version 11.0, 11.0.1, 11.0.2
- May 2017 - version 10.2.6
- April 2017 - version 10.2.4
- March 2017 - version 10.2.1
- February 2017 - version 10.2

Assuming that our app do not use any of the new functionalities in the newer SDK versions, which SDK version should we use in our app?

If using the newest version – I think some users will get "Update to the latest Google Play Services" prompt when starting our app.

If using a very old version – I think some bugs should have been fixed in the newer versions.